# Zend framework 1.11.11 with PHP 5.4 error

Tags: zend-framework

I am getting below error while accessing by website having PHP 5.4 version running on REHL-7 with Zend framework as 1.11.11.
Can anyone help in resolving the below issue.

> Error::
>   "Argument 1 passed to Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_HelperAbstract::setAcl() must be an instance of Zend_Acl, boolean given, called in /var/www/html/amov/library/Buza/Controller/Plugin/Navigation.php on line 48 and defined', '/var/www/html/amov/library/Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/HelperAbstract.php', 333"

Code in Navigation.php file:

```
    $view = $layout->getView();
    $view->navigation($navigation)
        ->pikeMenu()
        ->setACL(Zend_Registry::get('acl'))
        ->setRoles(Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->getRoles());
```

Code in HelperAbstract.php file:

```
public function setAcl(Zend_Acl $acl = null)
{
    $this->_acl = $acl;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Why do you still use ZF1? Upgrade! It's totally deprecated.

Comment: My Client don't wan.t to upgrade it, so we are using ZF1. ZFI1 will not work with PHP 5.4?

Comment: for Zend_Registry::get('acl'), do you getting ACL instance here, you should check for it.